# How to close an issue with GitHub API

Tags: python, github, github-api, issue-tracking, pygithub

I am trying to figure out how to close an issue through the Github API.

Specifically I'm trying to do it through pyGitHub and python, but knowing how to close an issue through the GitHub API would be enough to let me figure it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm sure it's simple but I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: Did you try my suggestion and do you confirm this works for you?

Comment: I have not yet, but I will try it today and mark if it works. Thank you for the advice, I would not have thought to try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not tested this right away but I think it is possible to close an issue by using [pyGitHub's edit function](http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Issue.html#github.Issue.Issue.edit), which in turn relies on [this entrypoint in GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue).

Basically it should suffice to set the `state` parameter to `"closed"`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. The exact code was 'prAsIssue.edit(state='closed')'. I am working on putting together some updated documentation examples for pyGitHub and this will certainly be in there. Thank you!